# (index):34 Uncaught TypeError: gooddata.login is not a function

Tags: gooddata

I am trying to do an inital setup of gooddata/d3js using gooddataJS sdk but it gives me this error:
"(index):34 Uncaught TypeError: gooddata.login is not a function"
Not sure why I am getting this error, I did exactly what was told oin get started for gooddataJS sdk and upon compiling it says cant find visualization.js.map and eventually goodata.login is not a function(I dont get any error for gooddata.js)

````html
```
<html lang="en">

<body class="app" bgcolor="#ffffff" style="display:block">

    <div id="root" class="app"></div>
    <h1>GoodData JS Project Template</h1>

    <!-- Dendencies of your project can be specified here -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../gooddata.js"></script>
    <script src="../viz/gooddata-js/dist/gooddata.js"></script>

    <script>
    var projectId = 'n4qgebtg809vbi573dvat2s28rizwkm0',
    user = "svs+analyticsimpl@eaab.com",
    passwd = "svs>";



// Show login info
$('body').append('<div class="login-loader">Logging in...</div>');


gooddata.login(user, passwd).then(function() {
    // Loged in
    $('div.login-loader').remove();
    $('body').append('<div class="loading">Loading data...</div>');
    gooddata.execution.getData(projectId, elements).then(function(dataResult) {
        console.log(dataResult);
    });
 
});

    
    </script>

    </body>
</html>```
````

Comment: Do you have gooddata.js in the local project directory? At least in the snippet you posted, it is not included, which would explain why `gooddata` is not defined

Comment: @TabsNotSpaces yeah I do have it as an include

Comment: And out of curiosity, if you comment out the `gooddata.login` statement and `console.log(gooddata)`, do you get an object back?

Comment: no thing the error i suppose is coming before, I think its not able to recognize gooddata object

Comment: {"referenceHandling":{},"DataLayer":{"Header":{},"DataSourceUtils":{},"DataSource":{},"Filters":{},"Uri":{"REG_URI_OBJ":{}},"ResultSpecUtils":{},"AfmUtils":{"ALL_TIME_GRANULARITY":"ALL_TIME_GRANULARITY"}},"TypeGuards":{},"default":{"configStorage":{"xhrSettings":{}},"config":{"configStorage":{"xhrSettings":{}}},"xhr":{"configStorage":{"xhrSettings":{}}},"user":{"xhr":{"configStorage":{"xhrSettings":{}}}},"md":{"xhr":{"configStorage":{"xhrSettings":{}}}},"execution":{"executeAfmModule":{"xhr":{"configStorage":{"xhrSettings":{}}}},"xhr":{"configStorage":{"xhrSettings":{}}}

Comment: this is what I get when I consoled goddata again

Comment: It is not apparent what version of gooddata js are using but in most recent one (I believe 6) login is not method of gooddata class. It's method from user module.
There is example shown on GIT portal https://github.com/gooddata/gooddata-js in "Using as a standalone library" section.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are calling the login method at wrong level. The "login" is part of "gooddata.user" not directly gooddata.
Your call should look like this:

```
gooddata.user.login(user, passwd).then(function()
```